# How can I determine where the Focus is *right now*?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, focus

### The short version

```
public class CustomDataGrid : DataGridControl, IXmlSettingsProvider
{
    public CustomDataGrid()
    {
        if (DesignModeHelper.IsInDesignMode) return;

        Loaded += (e, a) =>
                      {
                          ...
                      };

        LostFocus += (e, a) =>
                         {
                             if(IsBeingEdited /* &&
                                CurrentFocusTarget.GetType() == typeof(TabControl)*/)
                                EndEdit();
                         };
    }
}
```

How can I find `UIElement CurrentFocusTarget` in the above sample?

### The long version - Context

We use the XCeed DataGrid in order to show data in different tabs of a lazy-loaded TabControl. Each tab is lazy-loaded so that the content gets rendered (and, more importantly, the data is fetch) only when the tab is Visible. The whole data flow works great using the MVVM approach.

### The problem

Somehow, whenever the user makes changes to a cell and **Changes Tab**, the databound ViewModel property (that had already been updated) is being set to `null`.

In order to avoid this, it is possible to call EndEdit() when the focus is lost from the grid.

However, I only want to call it when the focus is lost to a TabItem (or the TabControl).

So, my question is:

**What is the easiest way to know where the `Focus` is *right now***, from the codebehind. I have inspected the `FocusManager` but can't seem to find the current Focus bearer (or to whom the focus is lost).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(Application.Current.MainWindow)
```

I might need a special case if the DataGrid is not hosted in the `Application.Current.MainWindow`.

Here is the complete code:

```
public class CustomDataGrid : DataGridControl, IXmlSettingsProvider
{
    public BSIDataGrid()
    {
        if (DesignModeHelper.IsInDesignMode) return;

        CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ResetDataGridLayout, ResetDataGridLayoutExecute, ResetDataGridLayoutCanExecute));

        Loaded += (e, a) =>
                      {
                          ...
                      };

        LostFocus += (e, a) =>
                         {
                             if(IsBeingEdited && IsTabFocused())
                                EndEdit();
                         };
    }

    private static bool IsTabFocused()
    {
        var dependencyObject = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(Application.Current.MainWindow);
        return dependencyObject is TabItem;
    }
}
```